# Display data in JSON URL using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic/angularjs and I need to know how to display data to a HTML view from a Json url.

So, data in my Json URL looks like this:

```
{
  News: [
        {
          id: "1",
          title: " It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
          image: "uploads/news/fortunaglobal_logo.jpg",
          status: "yes"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          title: "fgdf",
          description: "hhjgh",
          image: "uploads/news/16613_10204428208286459_7484489390034618482_n.jpg",
          status: "yes"
        }
      ]
}
```

I tried this in my script:

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {   

        $http.get('    "JSON URL"   ')
           .success(function(response, status, headers, config){

              window.alert('came in');
              if(status==200){

                 $scope.news = response.data['News'];
                 window.alert($scope.news );

              } else {
                 window.alert('No internet Connection');
              }
              console.log(news);
           })
          .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
              window.alert('error '+data+status);
              console.log(data);
              console.log(status);
         });
})
```

And this in my html page

```
<ion-view title="News" ng-controller="NewsCtrl">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>


    <ion-content  class="has-header" scroll="true" padding="true">




    <ul ng-repeat="newsS in news">
      <li>{{newsS.title}}</li>
    </ul>


    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with ionic, but to make your code simpler, you don't have to check for the status in the `success` handler, if you have no connection it'll go into `error`

Comment: Can you please add more information on what you want us to answer?

Comment: i want show the data in my json in a html view using angularjs

Comment: Yes but where is your problem right now? Does the console log show the desired data? dOes it display any data in your HTML? Does it display wrong data in your HTML? Are there any errors on your console?

Comment: it displays nothing. is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not specific enough I can only guess what you're trying to get at, but I see some things that might be problematic:

```
$scope.news = response.data['News'];
```

If your described JSON from above is the full response, this data should directly be contained in your response element (which is actually supposed to be named data according to the angular documentation).

So try this instead:

```
$scope.news = response.News;
```

Next thing that can't work is

```
console.log(news);
```

Your variable `news` is nowhere defined, maybe you meant to use `$scope.news`?

Comment: what should i do if i want to display a image from a url which is in the json.

Comment: For practice with a single image just add a `<img>` element to your News view, hook it up to an `ng-if=newsS.image` and set its `src` attribute as `src={{newS.image}}`